# Можно ли изменить переменную пользовательского скрипта через кнопку UI OnClick();

Tags: unity3d

Есть к примеру скрипт в котором есть переменная к примеру
bool a;

Как сделать что бы эта переменная высвечивалась как переменные isStatic, layer, name  у gameobject

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там переменные которые относятся именно объекту. Например `name` показывает имя объекта. Насколько я знаю там вы ничего не можете изменить.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем именно у GameObject? Просто это встроенный класс и изменить его не получится. Если тебе нужен там доступ к переменной твоего компонента, то добавь его в объект, который ты передал в событие и из списка выбери его, а не GameObject. Там и будет твой bool a.

Comment: Извиняюсь*            Не у GameObject а как у него , то есть у моего скрипта

Comment: И так как вы ответили не работает

Comment: @СергейГончаров, а переменная публичная?

Comment: именно!  Но спасибо я уже получил ответ на свой вопрос)

Comment: @СергейГончаров, рад что удалось решить проблему самостоятельно. :) Удачи вам в дальнейшем изучении движка.